# Executing Perl through PHP returns Exit Status 2

Tags: php, perl, bash

I am attempting to execute a Perl script through PHP via the following command:

```
$last_line = exec('/usr/bin/perl /path/to/perl/script.pl ' . escapeshellarg($argument),$output,$status);
```

The script does not perform its function, and the exit status is always 2 (improper use of shell builtins). Both Perl and the script can be read and executed by any user. Running the script on a command line works just fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: Does the user, who executes the php script, differ from the user, who executes the script from shell?

Comment: Yes, the apache2 user is failing to execute the script, while my normal user can execute it okay.

Comment: What error is printed to STDERR?

Comment: Most common errors: Permission error, or the script assumes the current work directory is the directory in which the script being executed resides.

Comment: Because I run the script through a web server when it fails, I don't get any error output messages.
Also, I use full filepaths to avoid the work directory mistake.

Comment: I also checked my apache logs, the error is never reported.

Comment: Well, the first thing to do would be to fix your error logging. Don't know PHP's `exec`... Could it be capturing it? Alternatively, does it have the option of capturing it?

Comment: This turned out to be a permissions problem, like ikegami suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to run file.pl located in same folder as php file

```
$output = passthru("perl relative_path/file.pl ".$_POST["var1"]." ".$_POST["var2"]);
```

Comment: The two scripts are in very different directories.

Comment: ok, then add relative path in before file name, passthru is the option that works, try it

Comment: I tried it your way, no dice.

Also, I need to analyze the output of the file, and according to the PHP manual (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php), I can't get the output using passthru.

Answer (score 0):

I use a perl script as a database interface from PHP with the following code:

```
exec ( $cmdToPass . " 2>&1" , $output , $returnVar);
```

Where:

- `$cmdToPass` is the command I'm executing (the perl script) with stderr redirected to stdout.
- `$output` holds the command's output
- `$returnVar` holds the exit code

You should then be able to print `$output` to determine why the script. You may also wish to check the PHP error log (usually the same as the web server's error log) to see if anything is captured there.

See the [PHP manual on exec](https://www.php.net/function.exec) if you need more info on the exec function.